# Use recursion for async loop: How to access push array data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

The idea is to run a geocode for multiple time (against array). To loop an async function, I decided to use recursion way.

```js
var geocoder = require('geocoder')
var geocoded = []

//Example array
var result = [{
  'company_no': 'A',
  'address': 'a'
}, {
  'company_no ': 'B',
  'address': 'b'
}]

function geocodeOneAsync(result, callback) {
  var n = result.length

  function tryNextGeocode(i) {
    if(i >= n) {
      //onfailure("alldownloadfailed")
      return
    }
    var address = result[i].address
    geocoder.geocode(address, function (err, data) {

      geocoded.push(result[i].company_no)
      console.log('data1' + JSON.stringify(
          geocoded)) //Result is ==> data1["A"], data1["B"]
      tryNextGeocode(i + 1)

      //  }
    })
  }
  console.log('data1' + JSON.stringify(geocoded))
  tryNextGeocode(0)
}
geocodeOneAsync(result, function () {
  JSON.stringify('data final ' + geocoded) // result is  empty []. I want to access the final geocoded array?

})
```

Basically the question how can I get the final value.

Comment: what the heck is goin on with that object at the top. the code formatting in your question needs to be improved.

Comment: Please use standard indentation to make your code readable. http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE can help.

Comment: You're never calling `callback` anywhere? Just use it in the base case.

Comment: opps. sorry..indent done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize if this does not answer your question.  I believe you need to call your callback in the recursion terminating condition:

```
if ( i >= n ) {
    callback();
}
```

Full code (I modified it for myself):

```
var geocoder = require('geocoder');
var geocoded = [];

function geocodeOneAsync(result, callback) {
    var n = result.length;
    function tryNextGeocode(ii) {
        if (ii >= n ) {
            //onfailure("alldownloadfailed")
            callback();
            return;
        }

        var address = result[ii].address
        geocoder.geocode(address, function (err, data) {
            geocoded.push(result[ii].company_no);
            console.log('data1' + JSON.stringify(geocoded)); //Result is ==> data1["A"], data1["B"]_++
            console.log("n=" +n + ",ii=" + ii);
            tryNextGeocode(ii + 1);
        });
    }
    console.log('data1' + JSON.stringify(geocoded));
    tryNextGeocode(0);
};

//Example array
var result = [
    {'company_no': 'A,','address': 'a'},
    {'company_no': 'B', 'address': 'b'}
];
geocodeOneAsync(result, function () {
     console.log(JSON.stringify('data final ' + geocoded)); // result is  empty []. I want to access the final geocoded array?
});
```

The output I get is:

```
data1[]
data1["A,"]
n=2,ii=0
data1["A,","B"]
n=2,ii=1
"data final A,,B"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Westandy...looks gr8

Answer (score 1):

For this the easiest would be to use map and Promise rather than recursion.

```
function geocodeOneAsync(result, callback) {
    // with map you get an array of promises
    var promises = result.map(function (company) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var address = company.address;
            geocoder.geocode(address, function (err, data) {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(company.company_no);
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // you can handle error here if you don't want the first occuring error to abort the operation.
        });
    });

    // then you resolve the promises passing the array of result to the callback.
    Promise.all(promises).then(callback);
}

geocodeOneAsync(result, function (geocodedArray) {
    // here geocoded is ['A','B']
    JSON.stringify(geocodedArray);
});
```

As an added bonus all async operation are done in parallel.

Comment: opps..tried the code..got an error with TypeError: result.map(...).catch is not a function

Comment: Oups Typo. The catch must be on new Promise not map.